# What's causing these weird characters to appear in this question?

Tags: support

[image]

It looks like some weird characters are appearing in the question [Do icons needs to be consistent across different themes](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16165/do-icons-need-to-be-consistent-across-different-themes?) How could this happen? What's causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I have edited that question, and removed the invalid characters from the end. I would guess that Flavius Franz used a word processor to create the question, and it added in some rubbish on the end.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Firebug displays it. The strange text can be removed (at via firebug) with no ill effects to the main question text.
 [image: How Firebug displays it]